# Field injection vs constructor injection - how does it make a difference in the way I write unit tests?

Tags: java, spring, junit

In my service class, I do **field** injection as :

```java
@Service
class ServiceLayer{

@Autowired
RepositoryLayer repository;
...
}
```

And in another service, I use **constructor** injection as:

```java
@Service
class ServiceLayer{

private final RepositoryLayer repository;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do unit tests, you will need to mock `RepositoryLayer` and use that mock in the `ServiceLayer`.

Usually, you have all dependencies as private (even in the first version you could do it, Spring would be able to inject it nevertheless). With this in mind is way harder to actually use the mocked `RepositoryLayer` in `ServiceLayer` while unit testing it. The reason is that in a unit test there is no Spring context and as such no injection would take place. As a consequence, you would need to set the mocked `RepositoryLayer` in `ServiceLayer` on your own. This is very easy when you use constructor injection, you just need to provide the mocked `RepositoryLayer` in the constructor call as follows:

```java
public class ServiceLayerTest {

    @Mock
    private RepositoryLayer repository;

    private ServiceLayer serviceLayer;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Mock RepositoryLayer behaviour

        this.serviceLayer = new ServiceLayer(this.repository);
    }

    // Your tests here
}
```

In the example I used Mockito `@Mock` but with constructor injection, you can even live without a mocking library.

Using field injection (and private without setter dependencies) you would need a mocking library to actually inject the mocks in your class under test. Imagine that your first version was as follows:

```java
@Service
class ServiceLayer{
  @Autowired
  private RepositoryLayer repository;

  // no setters for repository
  ...
}
```

So that you can actually unit test this class you would need a mocking library such as Mockito. You would do as follows:

```java
public class ServiceLayerTest {

    @Mock
    private RepositoryLayer repository;

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceLayer serviceLayer = new ServiceLayer();

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        // Mock RepositoryLayer behaviour
    }

    // Your tests here
}
```

This might not be a relevant difference between constructor and field injection but it actually is in my point of view. However, there are more advantages when you use constructor injection:

- All dependencies can be final and have no setter or getter, which means your class is immutable (if all dependencies are as well), and once the dependencies are set they cannot be changed.
- You clearly define the mandatory dependencies, otherwise, an instance of the class can't even be created. Field injection is ambiguous and doesn't really tell you which dependencies are mandatory.

Having written all this I strongly suggest using constructor injection, although field injection is perfectly valid as well.